# Sending null parameters from Angular controller cause unreachable function

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularCtrl where I receive a parameter, if it comes null, it just dont execute function:

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn blue" ng-click="insertar();">Accept</button>
```

**Angular controller**

```
    $scope.catalogoPadre = $stateParams.catalogopadre;

        if ($scope.catalogoPadre != null) {
            cargarCatalogo();
        }

        function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/", null,
               function (res) {
                   $scope.Catalogos = res.data;

                   $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];
                   inicial
                   $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
               }, errorCatalogo);
```

As you can see `cargarCatalogo` is a simple query that populates a `select`

Problem is when I try to execute `insertar` function (that is into `ng-click` of view), when I send all parameters, including `$scope.selected.ID` that I get into `cargarCatalogo()` function it runs correctly, but if I want to execute it without  `$scope.selected.ID` it don´t reach `insertar` function when I debbug chrome console.

**Angular Controller second part**

```
            $scope.filtro = function (selected) {

                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;

                $scope.insertar = insertar;


                function insertar() {

                    if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {
                        var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo;
                        if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
                            url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
                        }
                        apiService.post(url , null,
                            function (response) {
                                bootbox.alert("Operación Exitosa!");
                                $state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");
                            },
                            function (response) {

                                }
                            });
                    }
```

What can be wrong there? why  `$scope.insertar = insertar;` ´dont execute if I dont send all paramters if I have a validation

```
 if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
         url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
            }
```

Regards

**Update:**

I change code as alphapilgrim comment but it still dont fire `insertar` action when `$scope.selected.ID` comes null

**Code:**

```
 function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/", null,
               function (res) {
                 .
                   $scope.Catalogos = res.data;

                   $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];

                   $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
               }, errorCatalogo);


            $scope.filtro = function (selected) {
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;


                $scope.insertar = function() {
                    $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
                    if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {
                        var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo;
                        if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
                            url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
                        }
                        apiService.post(url, null,
                          function(response) {
                              bootbox.alert("Operación Exitosa!");
                              $state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");
                          },
                          function(response) {
                              if (response.status == "500") {
                                  window.location = "/";
                              } else {
                                  bootbox.alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText + "<br/>" + response.data.errores);
                              }
                          });
                      }
```

**Entire HTML**

```
<div class="page-head">
  <div class="page-title">
    <h1>
                Cat&aacute;logos Gen&eacute;ricos
                <small>Nuevo Registro de: {{tipoCatalogo}}</small>
            </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- BEGIN Portlet PORTLET-->
    <div class="portlet box blue">
      <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption">
          Cat&aacute;logos
        </div>
        <div class="tools">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse" data-original-title="" title=""> </a>
          <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="reload" data-original-title="" title=""> </a>-->
          <a href="javascript:;" class="fullscreen" data-original-title="" title=""> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-body">
        <!-- PITE - INICIA TABS -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- BEGIN Portlet PORTLET-->
            <div class="portlet box red">
              <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption" id="tab_titulo">
                  Nuevo registro de: {{tipoCatalogo}}
                </div>
                <div class="tools">
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"> </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="reload" ng-click="fill(conductor.ID); actualizardoctos();"> </a>
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="fullscreen"> </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="portlet-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_2_1">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <form id="detalle" name="detalle">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label> Código: </label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Codigo" name="Codigo" ng-model="Codigo" maxlength="3" required/>
                              <span ng-show="detalle.Codigo.$error.maxlength || detalle.Codigo.length" class="required">El Código debe contener 3 caracteres</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label> Nombre: </label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" ng-model="Nombre" maxlength="255" required />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-init="cargarCatalogo()">
                              <label ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0">Catalogo Padre: </label>

                              <select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
                              <br />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr width="100%" style="color: #2F353B;">
                        <div class="form-actions">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="text-right col-md-12">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn blue" ng-click="insertar();">Aceptar</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn default" ng-click="regresar();">Cancelar</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div ui-view> </div>
```

Comment: you have insertar inside of filtro, and why not make insetar a scoped function if your gonna use it on the view.

Comment: can you explain me how can I do it? I´m really confusted with Javascript and Angular, it´s not my forte :/ you say some thing like     use `$scope.insertar = insertar;` outside filtro?@alphapilgrim

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using controllerAs syntax and not attaching methods to your $scope. It will require a small bit of refactoring, but will result in much cleaner code.

Here's a plnkr showing converting a simplified version of your code to controllerAs syntax: http://plnkr.co/edit/yZuB5eEiZW15sNzqBIGS?p=preview

As [alphapilgrim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4812515/alphapilgrim) mentioned in the comment, you have your `insertar` method defined inside of `filtro`. If the `filtro` method is never called, as is most likely the case here, `insertar` will be null.

See https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ for a pretty good primer on how to switch over to controllerAs syntax. It's worth the effort in your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
    if ($scope.catalogoPadre != null) {
        cargarCatalogo();
    }
```

please use:

```
    if ($scope.catalogoPadre) {
        cargarCatalogo();
    }
```

It's more common and might fix your issue since it also check for undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the button as is, and change `insetar` function to a scoped function. This should get you going. This should fire the function now, then you'll just need to tweak it to whatever is missing.

```js
$scope.insertar = function() {
  $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
  if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {
    var url = "../../api/Catalogo/UpdateCatalogoRegistro/" + $scope.Codigo + "/" + $scope.Nombre + "/" + $scope.catalogoid + "/" + $scope.Catalogo;
    if ($scope.selected.ID != null) {
      url = url + "/" + $scope.selected.ID;
    }
    apiService.post(url, null,
      function(response) {
        bootbox.alert("Operación Exitosa!");
        $state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");
      },
      function(response) {

      }
    });
};
```

Comment: I change it as your comment, but action still unreachable when I have null  `$scope.selected.ID` I post an update of code in question. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ledwing can you share more of your HTML, maybe a scope issue. button might not have access to your controller.

Comment: I post my entire HTML page, I dont see nothing to consider an issue or maybe in select `ng-hide` can do something?

Comment: If you can see I still using  `$scope.filtro = function (selected) {
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;` outside `$scope.insertar` because I need it to call `$scope.selectedID = selected.ID;` is that wrong?